# How to select hierarchical records from two tables using join

Tags: sql, join, hierarchy

Actually I want to select matched records from two tables with hierarchical data from the first table

I have two tables:

1. tmpos_category table with **columns (category_refid(pk),category_name,parent_ref_id)**. i am storing hierarchical data in it.
2. tmpos_menu_child table with **columns (id(pk),title,category_ref_ids(fk))**. category_ref_ids field from tmpos_menu_child table references the **category_refid field of tmpos_category table**.

[this is a tmpos_category table with hierarchical categories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZLpYb.png)

[image]

[tmpos_menu_child table with **category_ref_ids as fk refrances category(category_refid )** column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKnn4.png)

[image]

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ct.category_name,ct.category_refid,ct.parent_ref_id
from tmpos_category ct
JOIN tmpos_menu_child tmc
ON ct.category_refid = tmc.category_ref_ids
```

Now My Question is when i join tmpos_category table and tmpos_menu_child table i will get all distinct matched category but i also want selected category parent records

Comment: can you please check the question now

Comment: Why are you joining to `tmpos_menu_child` if you're not going to use any of its columns?

Comment: You say the first table contains columns named `id`, `category name`, and `parent id`, but they appear to be named `category_refid`, `category_name`, and `parent_ref_id`. --- You say the second table contains columns named `id`, `item name`, and `category_id`, but the first two are not shown in the image or query and the last appear to be named `category_ref_ids`. --- So which is it? Please be accurate and specify correct names. Programming requires being exact in what you write, and you should apply that same rigorousness when writing questions.

Comment: This is not clear. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. When giving a business relation(ship)/association or table (base or query result), say what a row in it states about the business situation in terms of its column values. Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For errors that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) [ask] For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL, which includes constraints & indexes & tabular initialization.

Comment: @Andreas updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can only have 2 levels in your hierarchy, i.e. a parent cannot itself have a parent, then two JOINs will do it.

```sql
SELECT i.id AS item_id, i.title AS item_title
     , c.category_refid, c.category_name
     , c.parent_ref_id, p.category_name AS parent_name
  FROM tmpos_menu_child i
  JOIN tmpos_category c ON c.category_refid = i.category_ref_ids
  LEFT JOIN tmpos_category p ON p.category_refid = c.parent_ref_id
```

If the hierarchy can be deep, you should use a hierarchical query, which in most DBMS's are done with a recursive CTE (common table expression).

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE Item_and_Cat (item_id, item_title, category_level,
                             category_refid, category_name, parent_ref_id) AS (
   SELECT i.id AS item_id, i.title AS item_title
        , c.category_refid, c.category_name
        , 1 AS category_level, c.parent_ref_id
     FROM tmpos_menu_child i
     JOIN tmpos_category c ON c.category_refid = i.category_ref_ids
   UNION ALL
   SELECT i.item_id, i.item_title
        , p.category_refid, p.category_name
        , i.category_level + 1 AS category_level, p.parent_ref_id
     FROM Item_and_Cat i
     JOIN tmpos_category p ON p.category_refid = i.parent_ref_id
)
SELECT item_id, item_title, category_refid, category_name, category_level
  FROM Item_and_Cat
```

*Note:* The `RECURSIVE` keyword is required for PostgreSQL and MySQL, but not allowed for Oracle DB and SQL Server.

---

**UPDATE**

From [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60235862/how-to-select-hierarchical-records-from-two-tables-using-join/60236496?noredirect=1#comment106548026_60236496):

> i want there parents as record(in seperate row)

To get parent records as separate rows, run the query twice and combine with `UNION`.

```sql
SELECT i.id AS item_id, i.title AS item_title
     , c.category_refid, c.category_name, 0 AS is_parent
  FROM tmpos_menu_child i
  JOIN tmpos_category c ON c.category_refid = i.category_ref_ids
UNION ALL
SELECT i.id AS item_id, i.title AS item_title
     , p.category_refid, p.category_name, 1 AS is_parent
  FROM tmpos_menu_child i
  JOIN tmpos_category c ON c.category_refid = i.category_ref_ids
  JOIN tmpos_category p ON p.category_refid = c.parent_ref_id
```

Comment: # category_name, category_refid, parent_ref_id, parent_name
'Winter Special Menu', '4563', '0', NULL
'Tai Chi Bowl Meals', '4564', '0', NULL
'Veg Bao', '4573', '4572', 'Bao'
'Non Veg Bao', '4574', '4572', 'Bao'
'Veg Dimsum', '4569', '4568', 'Dimsum'
'Veg Soup', '4566', '4565', 'Soup'
'Chicken Dimsum', '4570', '4568', 'Dimsum'
'Non Veg Soup', '4567', '4565', 'Soup'
'Seafood Dimsum', '4571', '4568', 'Dimsum'
'Veg Starter', '4576', '4575', 'Starter'
'Chicken & Lamb Starter', '4577', '4575', 'Starter'
Got proper output but i want there parents as record(in seperate row)

Comment: @Nilesh You never said that in the question, but see second part of answer, it will return all parent, grandparent, etc rows separately, with the `category_level` specifying how far up the parent chain to row comes from.

Comment: How to run the second part of answer script in MySQL workbench its giving error

Comment: @Nilesh Must be MySQL 8.

Answer (score 0):

So when using this schema with `parent_ref_id` on the `category table`, it is going to be tough to move up the hierarchy and get all ancestor categories without writing queries that hardcode 1 join for each parent.

If you're only ever going to have 2 or 3 generations (child, parent, grandparent for example) then this is okay, but with more (or variable levels) it can get messy. One solution is to use "recursive syntax" but not all SQL implementations support it as far as I know.

Bill Karwin has an excellent slide deck that details the pros/cons of your schema (commonly referred to as "adjacency lists").

you can find that on slides 6-17 here:

https://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/models-for-hierarchical-data

He details your problem rather nicely, and offers several other strategies for modeling hierarchies if you end up having trouble with your current schema. I personally like the last one detailed in that deck, which is called a "closure table"

**EDIT**

If you are in fact only trying to include one or two parent levels, then your query will look quite similar to any query joining 3 or more tables, only you will have to join the `categories` table to itself. It should be pretty easy to find examples of this if you google "join a table to itself" or something similar